# Program opened with batch file won't work

Tags: batch-file

At work I use a bunch of different programs that are located in many different folders that I have to open when I get here.  So I've created a batch file that opens all of them for me.

I've run into an issue with one program that's located on a shared network.  In my batch file I put

`START "" "\\server\path\program.exe"`

It loads the program but when I try to navigate the program is doesn't work. I run into an exception error that says it can't find a file on the C drive. But when I load the same program from the folder without the batch file, it works just fine.  Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Try `START "" /D "\\server\path" "\\server\path\program.exe"` - specify the working folder as well.

Comment: Cool, converted to answer in that case :P

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the working folder:

```
START "" /D "\\server\path" "\\server\path\program.exe"
```

It's documented in the output of `start /?`.